# Migrating .aspx pages created on SharePoint 2010

Tags: deployment, migration

We're developing a solution based on a closed-source SharePoint-based application here at work and we're pretty stuck on the deployment portion.

We have 2 servers, production and development. We need a simple - automated - way of deploying the application. We create .aspx pages with a custom (again, source-closed) webpart and some configurations for each "module".

Is there a way to create .aspx pages automatically on the development server, putting this custom webpart in it and doing the necessary configurations? I've seen a software on codeplex that does this, so it should be feasible. This would improve our deployment strategy a LOT. Currently we deploy the database portion and have to build every page by hand again :(

Thanks for any help.

Gustavo Ramos

Comment: hate to be overly simple, but, have you tried to export your work in development to a site template using the end-user GUI side of SharePoint?